# Sencha touch Licence

Tags: sencha-touch

I am new to mobile technology . I want to create my personal portfolio in Sencha touch. 
Am I need to pay for that ?

Answer (score 10):

No, you will not. I would recommend using the Commercial license though, as it's free and has fewer restrictions on what you can do with it. You only need to pay if you want support, or are creating a project or product that would have you distributing Sencha Touch's codebase to anyone but an end-user (i.e. a development kit), or using the license in anything that resembles an app building tool or platform.

Also note that if you were to use their GPLv3 version, you cannot submit apps to the Apple App Store as you would require a special license to be issued to you by Sencha to do this without violating the GPL.

Answer (score 4):

no. sencha-touch available under GPL.
http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/license/

Comment: It's worth noting that if you use the GPLv3 version of Sencha you're required to release the source of both your web frontend that uses Sencha and your backend code. Read their site very carefully if you use the GPL version.

Comment: thats true, there is also a commercial license free of charge though.

Comment: Yes, do read their notes on their interpretation of GPLv3, it is very well described. That said, its only their interpretation and the GPLv3 itself is the only real license. Consult a lawyer if you're doing something where there's a mix of GPLv3 and proprietary -- it's possible to do, but has to be done correctly with enough distance between the two.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on at0mzk's answer, the only thing you would ever need to pay for is if you wanted to build your own commercial framework or app builder using sencha touch.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to pay. You don't need to share your code.

Sencha touch is licensed under multiple licenses, one them being GPL. Like already said GPL require you to publish your code. You can also create code without releasing your code using Free Commercial license. (not sure how it can be done in JavaScript)

The only thing you can't do is building closed-sounce SDK or Builder application and distributing it commercially, because Sencha is reserving those rights for their future products, probably something similar to Dashcode.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch is released under two licenses: GPL or a commercial one. Both are free.

See: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/

Sencha Touch Charts (the charts addon for Touch) is released under two licenses: GPL or a commercial one. But only the GPL one is free.

Option 1: Use GPL/Open Source and share your code. Option 2: Buy the commercial license and keep your code. Simple and, imho, fair.

See: http://www.sencha.com/products/charts/download/